FormData send empty objects to the server
I want to upload media files picked from:
 <input
    accept="image/*,.pdf"
    multiple
    id="dropzone-file"
    type="file"
    className="hidden"
    onChange={handleFileChange}
 />

Handled by:
  const handleFileChange = (e: { target: { files: any } }) => {
    const files = e.target.files;
    setFiles([...files]);
  };


Mutation:

onClick={() =>
            uploadMediaMutation.mutate({
              data: {
                media: files,
              },
            })
          }


API call:


export const uploadMedia = (data: { data: UploadMedia }) => {
  const { media } = data.data;

  console.log(media); // Media is here, format below

  const formData = new FormData();

  for (let x = 0; x < media.length; x++) {
    formData.append('media[]', media[x]);
  }

  return api.post(`/media/bulk-upload`, formData); // but not here, payload below
};


Media from state:

(4) [File, File, File, File]
0
: 
File {name: 'autobuske stanice.png', lastModified: 1716551697000, lastModifiedDate: Fri May 24 2024 13:54:57 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time), webkitRelativePath: '', size: 15176, …}
1
: 
File {name: 'carinske ispostave.png', lastModified: 1716551697000, lastModifiedDate: Fri May 24 2024 13:54:57 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time), webkitRelativePath: '', size: 15984, …}
2
: 
File {name: 'centri za socijalni rad.png', lastModified: 1716551697000, lastModifiedDate: Fri May 24 2024 13:54:57 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time), webkitRelativePath: '', size: 19972, …}
3
: 
File {name: 'domace zakonodavstvo.png', lastModified: 1716551697000, lastModifiedDate: Fri May 24 2024 13:54:57 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time), webkitRelativePath: '', size: 20207, …}
length
: 
4

Payload to the server:
{"media":[{},{},{},{}]}

